# Making desktop installers for apps?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have been using electron for a while and have built several apps, but have not figured out exactly how to go about creating a desktop icon and windows installer (on the electron homepage, it says specifically that making windows installers is "made easy".)

How would I go about making such an installer for windows, as well as having automatically installed desktop icons (.desktop for GNOME, shortcut for windows), for an app in a typical electron setup?

I know this might seem like a stupid question, but I just can't understand less specific instructions (e.g. http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.34.0/tutorial/application-distribution/ sort of helps but is too vague.)

Answer (score 1):

I have done some research before and found that, well, it is not that easy to create a windows installer.

1. Use [grunt-electron-installer](https://github.com/atom/grunt-electron-installer) to create a Windows installer. Note that it will only show a gif while installing. There is no interactive dialog. It uses [Squirrel.Windows](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows).
2. Use `Update.exe --createShortcut=<comma separated locations> <your exe>` to create shortcuts. Available locations include `Desktop`, `StartMenu`, `Startup` and `AppRoot`

   `Update.exe` will be shipped together with your app when you install. I found [this article](http://www.mylifeforthecode.com/tag/windows-installer/) very helpful. In short, you need something like this:

   ```
   var app = require('app');
   var path = require('path');
   var cp = require('child_process');

   var handleSquirrelEvent = function() {
      if (process.platform != 'win32') {
         return false;
      }

      function executeSquirrelCommand(args, done) {
         var updateDotExe = path.resolve(path.dirname(process.execPath), 
            '..', 'update.exe');
         var child = cp.spawn(updateDotExe, args, { detached: true });
         child.on('close', function(code) {
            done();
         });
      };

      function install(done) {
         var target = path.basename(process.execPath);
         executeSquirrelCommand(["--createShortcut", target], done);
      };

      function uninstall(done) {
         var target = path.basename(process.execPath);
         executeSquirrelCommand(["--removeShortcut", target], done);
      };

      var squirrelEvent = process.argv[1];
      switch (squirrelEvent) {
         case '--squirrel-install':
            install(app.quit);
            return true;
         case '--squirrel-updated':
            install(app.quit);
            return true;
         case '--squirrel-obsolete':
            app.quit();
            return true;
         case '--squirrel-uninstall':
            uninstall(app.quit);
            return true;
      }

      return false;
   };

   if (handleSquirrelEvent()) {
      return;
   }
   ```

Note that in a newer version of Electron, you can use `auto-updater` to handle Squirrel.Windows events, but the API is a bit different so I'm not sure how to do it correctly using `auto-updater`.